# Ruby: How to get an article's main image OR how does a link preview work?

Tags: ruby, parsing

I am trying to understand how a link preview works (e.g. seen on sites like Facebook or Reddit where an article's image and their caption is previewed when posting links): How do I get the "main" image of an article without knowing its exact image url?

For example on this [site](https://www.theguardian.com/technology/2016/dec/12/facebook-2016-problems-fake-news-censorship) my link previewer should show me this [image](https://i.guim.co.uk/img/media/0b0c6ed1373938bf2802e21a07ddfa37b311292f/223_114_2330_1398/master/2330.jpg) (the "main" image) instead of for example [this one](https://i.guim.co.uk/img/media/cb058890f280f089223e442928817d98a138aea9/0_0_5422_3253/master/5422.jpg?w=880&q=20&auto=format&usm=12&fit=max&dpr=2&s=fb7d4bcbff4203dd4e309695d36b6586) (which is an image further down).

I am a ruby newbie but I was able to get all the images with Nokogiri and Open-Uri with this code (however the question remains: How do I only get the main image?):

```
URL = "https://www.theguardian.com/technology/2016/dec/12/facebook-2016-problems-fake-news-censorship"

require 'open-uri'
require 'nokogiri'

Nokogiri::HTML(open(URL)).xpath("//img/@src").each do |src|
  uri = URI.join( URL, src ).to_s
  File.open(File.basename(uri), 'wb') do |f|
    f.write(open(uri).read) 
  end
end
```

Comment: Try this http://ogp.me/

Comment: You cannot write a programm that will understand what you mean with "main image". Will you always access the same page (in your example theguardian)? Then you have to inspect the pages source code (and hope it will not change too soon) and find e.g. a defining css-class/selector.

Comment: @Felix: I want to access different pages, so I guess this is rather a very difficult task. I know that there a lot of great ruby gems, e.g. [Link Thumbnailer](https://github.com/gottfrois/link_thumbnailer) which work fine, however I want to understand how they do it (e.g. do they only parse the first image which is greater than a width/height threshold etc.?)

Answer (score 1):

Here's a slightly modified version of your code. It works fine for the provided link, you'll have to adapt it to for other websites.

It parses the code for images URL with `w=` followed by a number greater than 300.

It downloads the first found image, possibly with a higher resolution (`desired_width = 800`)

```
URL = 'https://www.theguardian.com/technology/2016/dec/12/facebook-2016-problems-fake-news-censorship'.freeze

require 'open-uri'
require 'nokogiri'

minimum_width = 300
desired_width = 800
width_regex   = /(w=)(\d+)/

Nokogiri::HTML(open(URL)).xpath('//img/@src').find do |src|
  basename = File.basename(src)

  next unless basename =~ width_regex &&
    Regexp.last_match(2).to_i >= minimum_width

  without_parameters = basename.split('?').first
  puts "Found #{without_parameters} !"
  uri = URI.join(URL, src.to_s.sub(width_regex, '\1' + desired_width.to_s))

  File.open(without_parameters, 'wb') do |f|
    f.write(open(uri).read)
  end
end
```

For the given example :

```
Found 2330.jpg !
```